# How to show a block for particalur menu's sub menu Drupal 7

Tags: drupal

I have using drupal for my work. My project has 6 main menus. All 6 menus are Multi level menus. I have to show a block for the 3 main and their child menus.
For that, i would like to know how to apply main and child menus by give main menu name only. For example, About main menu has 20 menus (multilevel). How to apply block show for all about menu and child menus.

Or should i type manually enter all names

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. We can put asterix symbol at the end of the page name. For example  About * . This would affect all children menus of "About".